# What is the best way to find out / approximate time and space complexities of the code?

Tags: python, function, big-o

It's not particularly obvious to me.
Sure, if your code just iterates through all n elements in the list every time, then we're looking at O(n) time. But what about all the built-in functions? I'm super new to Python (and coding in general). So how do you know if a certain function has to iterate through elements or if it somehow just pulls the element you need right away like in a hash table? >.> ...
For example, at first I didn't know that every time you update a list, a whole new list is actually created and repopulated. That's a whole lot more steps than just slapping an element to the backside like I thought it did before %\
So what else out there takes a lot longer behind the scenes? X.x

Comment: reason for downvote and constructive feedback? .......

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there isn't an easy answer for this. Well written code will often have comments telling you the runtime of each method but that's not always the case. If you're using a method someone else wrote and they didn't document the runtime of their method then the only option is to look at the code and figure it out.

As you gain more experience you'll find it easier to guess the complexity of a function. This comes from knowing what data structures are being used and what the code you're calling is going to have to do.

Comment: That is true. But is there a place where the inner workings of all the built-in python methods are described so that I know which ones are more efficient in certain instances? Like array vs tuple and such.